# Who proved that a triangulation is 3-colourable implies its dual is bipartite

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-colouring, ho.history-overview

Let $G$ be a maximal planar graph (also called a triangulation); i.e, $G$ is a planar graph every face of which is a triangle. It is well known that the following three statements are equivalent:
(i) $G$ is 3-colourable
(ii) dual graph $G^*$ of $G$ is bipartite
and (iii) $G$ is Eulerian (i.e., every vertex has even degree).

I am interested in direct constructive proof of (i) $\iff$ (iii).
**I would like to know who came up with this proof; esp. the proof of (i)$\implies$ (ii) given below**

(i) $\implies$ (ii):
Suppose $G^*$ has a 3-face colouring $f$ with colours 1,2,3. Then, one can obtain a 2-colouring $f^*$ of $G^*$ by assigning colour +1 at a vertex $v$ if colours 1,2,3 appear clockwise on faces around $v$, and colour -1 at $v$ if 1,2,3 appear counterclockwise around $v$. So, $G^*$ is bipartite.

David Gale wrote to Shen giving a proof for (i) $\iff$ (iii) using homology theory (for triangulations of the sphere). In that letter, he proves that the mapping $f\to f^*$ given in the proof above is in fact a bijection (answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719936/120721) explains why). Shen explains these in [Mathematical Entertainments 20(3)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03024801). I think that Gale's proof is different for the direction (i)$\implies (ii)$ (I am not sure, homology theory is Greek to me). I guess this proof should be known already because it is easier than the other direction. So, like I said, I would like to know who came up with this proof of (i)$\implies (ii)$ first.

Tsai and West's paper [A new proof of 3-colorability of Eulerian triangulations](https://amc-journal.eu/index.php/amc/article/viewFile/193/124) refer to Lovász ([Combinatorial Problems and Exercises](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780444815040/combinatorial-problems-and-exercises), Problem number is 9.52 I suppose) and to Shen (reference given above).

Thank you.

Comment: In a comment to this answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2727059/120721), Misha Lavrov points out that Lovász attributes a proof of (ii) $\implies$ (i) to Whitney.

Answer (score 2):

This result is included in Ore's book [*The Four-Colour Problem*](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-four-color-problem/ore/978-0-12-374571-2) (see Theorem 7.4.3).

I saw a paper that states this as a folklore result and cites Ore. Interestingly, the book gives a different proof for (ii)$\implies$(i). It seems that at that time, it wasn't known that the mapping $f\longmapsto f^*$ is a bijection.

Sorry to disappoint; but that's the best I could trace back.